# Company Team page navbar (left) bleeds into footer

Tags: bug, design

I was just reading all about the team that makes this network of websites awesome, and eventually scrolled to the bottom of the page only to find:

[image: nav bleeds into footer]

The nav should stop float-scrolling with the rest of the page once its bottom margin hits the top margin of the footer.